# Facebook posting on facebook page 

Tags: facebook, cron

When i run this code on facebook,as an app,it post on my facebook fan page wall but this does not work,when i run them as a .Where do i go wrong?Is any thing else need to run .

Thanks in-advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

have you got the offline_access permission from the user? it may not post on wall if access_token is not valid. Verify that you have that permission.